# Angular run filter only when needed

Tags: angularjs, performance

I am using filter to filter result that looks something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="searchController" searchbar>
   <input type="text" id="searchfield" ng-model="myVar">
   <div searchresult>
       <div ng-repeat="data in data.menu | myfilter: myVar">
           {{data.title}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

angular.filter('myfilter',function() {
    return function(data,filtertext){
        console.log("run filter");
    }
}
```

It does work. But the problem is, it keep on running the filter even if I just mouse moving on the screen. How can I make the filter only run & update when there is changes to `myVar`?

Comment: There's something else going on, it shouldn't fire all the time like that.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? Also, do you have an `ng-mousemove` defined on your body tag or something like that? Something is causing the digest to be run every time you move the mouse, which is going to be _horrendous_ for performance for anything beyond a very simple app.

Comment: @GregL Thanks a lot for your comment. I am using version 1.3. I found out that it is because of one of my directive is using `$document.on('mouseover', function(event){});` to detect mouseover on popup menu causes the problem. As this is the case, how can I detect mouseover while not cause performance issue?

Comment: Inside the mouseover handler function, is the directive code calling `$scope.$apply()`? That's the bit that is slow, because it digests the whole scope tree from the root scope down. Possibilities to fix this: only call `$scope.$digest()` if the directive scope is the only one that will have changed, or throttle the function execution (using [Lodash](http://lodash.js) or UnderscoreJS) so it doesn't execute so often, or other techniques you might come up with. I would probably try to combine the two approaches I mentioned, since the `mousemove` event occurs so often.